# Правильно ли  затранскрибирован текст?

Tags: фонетика, транскрипция

Как рано мог он лицемерить,

Таить надежду, ревновать,

Разуверять, заставить верить,

Казаться мрачным, изнывать,

Являться гордым и послушным,

Внимательным иль равнодушным!

Как томно был он молчалив,

Как пламенно красноречив,

В сердечных письмах как небрежен!

Одним дыша, одно любя,

Как он умел забыть себя!

Как взор его был быстр и нежен,

Стыдлив и дерзок, а порой

Блистал послушною слезой!

**Обновление**

```
ка́к ра́нъ мо́к о́н /лицемерить/,
тʌи́т' нʌд'е́жду, р'иевнʌва́т',
Разуверять/, зʌста́в'иет' в'е́р'иет',
кʌза́цъ мра́чныэм, /изнывать/,
jиевл'а́цъ го́рдыэм и́ пʌслу́шныэм,
вн'иема́т'иел'ныэм и́л' ръвнʌду́шныэм!
ка́к то́мнъ бы́л о́н мълчиел'и́ф,
ка́к /пламенно/ кръснър'иечи́ф,
ф_с'иерд'е́чныэх п'и́с'мъх ка́к /небрежен/!
```

Comment: @мира, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: помогите найти в тексте слова, в которых написание приставок, корней, суффиксов, окончаний основано на а) фонематическом принципе; б) морфологическом принципе (по МФШ); в) на фонетическом принципе; г) на традиционном принципе; д) на дифференцирующем принципе.

Comment: правильно ли: морфологический принцип - казаться, являться. фонетический - мог, его, разуверять?

Answer (score 1):

кʌк_ра́нъ мо́г_он  л'ицыэм'э́р'ит'/

тʌи́т' нʌд'э́жду/ р'иэвнʌва́т'/

ръзув'иэр'а́т'/ зʌста́в'ит' в'э́р'ит'/

кʌза́цъ мра́чным /изныва́т'/

jиэвл'а́цъ го́рдым ипʌслу́шным/

вн'има́т'иэл'ным   ил'ръвнʌду́шным//

кʌкто́мнъ бы́лън мълчиэли́ф//

кʌкпла́м'ьнъ  кръснър'иэчиф/

фс'иэрд'е́чных п'и́с'мъх къкн'иэбр'эжън//

ʌдн'им дыша́ /ʌдно́ л'уб'а́/

кʌко́н ум'э́л зʌбы́т'  сиэба́//

кʌквзо́р jиво́ был бы́стр ин'эжън/

стыдл'ив и д'э́рзък/ а пʌрой

бл'иста́л пʌслу́шнъjу  сл'иэзо́й//

Comment: СПАСИБО, БОЛЬШОЕ!!!